# CKFinder and composer version conflicts

Tags: php, composer-php, ckfinder

I am working integrating CKFinder (3.1.0) with an existing application. I'd like to use the S3 adapter for storage, which works fine in isolation in the application.

The problem I am having is that the download package for CKFinder 3.1.0 includes its own vendor directory of libraries, including the AWS SDK (v2.27) - I have my own instance of the AWS sdk loaded via composer which is a much more recent version which is conflicting with CKFinder's version, causing errors.

Has anyone had any success is running CKFinder with it's local vendor files alongside project-wide composer libraries such as aws-sdk-php. I can convert to using the 2.27 version of the aws-sdk project wide, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

CKFinder 3 PHP connector doesn't support installation with Composer yet, but you can modify your `composer.json` file to make it use application dependencies.

1. Add following connector dependencies to your `composer.json` (valid for CKFinder 3.1.0):

   ```
   "symfony/http-kernel": ">=2.4,<=2.8-dev",
   "symfony/event-dispatcher": ">=2.4,<=2.8-dev",
   "symfony/http-foundation": ">=2.4,<=2.8-dev",
   "pimple/pimple": "~3.0",
   "monolog/monolog": "~1.4,>=1.4.1",
   "league/flysystem": "1.0.14",
   "league/flysystem-dropbox": "1.0.0",
   "dropbox/dropbox-sdk": "~1.1.1",
   "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.7.17",
   "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2": "1.0.3",
   "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "1.0.2"
   ```
2. Extract connector code from CKFinder package to a separate directory and make it loadable in Composer. Assuming the code will be located in `_connector` directory:

   - Move the contents from the `/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/cksource/ckfinder/src/CKSource/CKFinder` directory in the distribution ZIP to `_connector`.
   - Add it to composer autoloader using a proper namespace:

     ```
     "autoload": {
         "psr-4": {
              // ...
              "CKSource\\CKFinder\\": "_connector"
          }
     }
     ```
   - Alter `/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php` to use `autoload.php` from your application.

**Important**: If you are using AWS-S3 **version 3.x** SDK in your app, then there's no way to resolve this conflict. CKFinder will not work properly with this version, as AWS-SDK v3 is not backward compatible with v2.7.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I use AWS sdk v3 for my application, so this is a problem. I have managed to get it working for now, but only by modifying the CKFinder S3 adapter code, which is not ideal for upgrade reasons.